# Unable to send data to Sitecatalyst with function CQ_Analytics.record

Tags: aem, adobe-analytics

I am working on a POC involving  AEM and site catalyst integration .

I am using AEM’s out of box  Geomatrixx outdoors website which already implements  site catalyst features.

Data is being populated to report suite via 
•   Data tracking (on page load)
data-tracking="{'event': ['eventName'], 'values': {'key': 'value', 'nextKey': 'nextValue'}, componentPath: 'myapp/component/mycomponent'}"

•   CQ_Analytics.record(after page load, activates on  a page).

CQ_Analytics.record({event: 'eventName', values: { valueName: 'VALUE' }, collect:  false, options: { obj: this, defaultLinkType: 'X' }, componentPath: '<%=resource.getResourceType()%>'})

UseCase: When, I am adding  a product to cart  below function gets executed CQ_Analytics.record But unable to send cart addition data to site catalyst .
                 I have  verified same using adobe digital debugger.

Code snippet from  /libs/commerce/components/product/product.jsp
function trackCartAdd(form) {

```
    if (CQ_Analytics.Sitecatalyst) {
        var productQuantity = Number($("input[name='product-quantity']", form).val() || '1');
        var productPrice    = Number($("input[name='product-size']:checked", form).data('price').replace(/[^0-9\\.]/g, ''));
        var productChildSku =        $("input[name='product-size']:checked", form).data('sku')

    CQ_Analytics.record({
                "event": ["cartAdd"<%= (session.getCartEntryCount() == 0) ? ", 'cartOpen'" : "" %>],
                "values": {
                    "product": [{
                          "category": "",
                          "sku": "<%= xssAPI.encodeForJSString(baseProduct.getSKU()) %>",
                        "price": productPrice * productQuantity,
                        "quantity": productQuantity,
                          "evars": {
                          "childSku": CQ.shared.Util.htmlEncode(productChildSku)
                          }
                    }]
                },
                "componentPath": "<%= xssAPI.encodeForJSString(resource.getResourceType()) %>"
        });
    }
    return true;

}
```

Note: I have done the product variable mapping for report suite in AEM.
Please guide me .

Comment: u can pass product in a string delimited as follows s.products="category;product;quantity;price;eventY={value}|eventZ={value};evarA={value}|evarB={value}"


this is found in http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/integrating_with_adobe_marketing_cloud/sitecatalyst.html